# Page numbers remain in center for every first page in chapter

Tags: latex

I have a problem with the page numbers. They should be one the right which they are, except for the very first page in every new chapter. There they're still in the center.

Edit: This is now compilable so you can have a look on the page numbers. I would really appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass[
    11pt,               
    a4paper,            
    DIV=13,             
    BROC=5mm            
    twoside,            
    parskip=half,       
    bibtotoc,       
    openright,      
    cleardoubleempty    
    ]{scrreprt}         
            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}          

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\cfoot{}
\chead{}

\automark[section]{chapter}
\ohead{\headmark}               
\ofoot{\pagemark}               
    
\begin{document}        
\chapter{test}
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
\chapter{failed}
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I can't get rid of that, any suggestions?

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] that allows us to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the numbers in the centre with `\clearscrheadfoot` and then add them on the outer edge with `\ofoot*{\pagemark}`

```
\documentclass[
    11pt,               
    a4paper,            
    DIV=13,             
    BROC=5mm            
    twoside,            
    parskip=half,       
    bibtotoc,       
    openright,      
    cleardoubleempty    
    ]{scrreprt}         
            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}          

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\cfoot{}
\chead{}

\automark[section]{chapter}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\headmark}               
\ofoot*{\pagemark}          
     
    
\begin{document}        
\chapter{test}
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
\chapter{failed}
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
\end{document}
```